# Configuration Module left right picture slideshow joomla

Tags: joomla

I used Joomla 3. I want a slider picture module in the left. I find module ***left right picture slideshow Joomla***. it is perfect as I want. 
the problem is in a configuration the module in ***image folder*** I create a folder in content media I created a folder 'Test' in the root images that contains jpg.
alos in field image folder 'I wrote **\images\test** but I do try walking with **\images** but the same case. I wonder why not worked

Comment: i'm sorry for my bad english language

Comment: Try with `images/test`.

Comment: not worked images\test and images/test

Comment: in fontend the  test module display " No directory \var\www\vhosts\bahri.it\httpdocs\images
NO IMAGES images
"

Comment: No directory \var\www\vhosts\bahri.it\httpdocs\images est
NO IMAGES images est

Comment: Check folder permissions. Remove \ or / on start of your path.

Comment: I have already taken the path is images/test  folder permission is is configured